# XAML - Dynamic creation of different GridViews from only a Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, dynamic

I'm trying to create some dynamic gridviews using a List.

Here's my situation, I have a List of Object that has some attributes: name, description, group.

I want to create a Gridview for every single group type.

Is there a way to "filter" the source or maybe to group the source?

(P.S. Sorry for the bad english, I've tryed my best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem.

I've used:

```
var result = from act in list
             group act by act.groupname into grp
             orderby grp.Key
             select grp;
```

And used the *result* as source of a GridView

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this "filter/groups" in the VM where you have this list of elements and then you can easily bind those collections to grids.

```
public ObservableCollection<YourEntity> get{ return OriginalCollection.Where(x=> x.Group == "TargetGroup")}
```